# Managing MySQL query in PHP with MySQLi

Tags: c#, php, mysqli

I'm needing to use PHP to access the MySQL database on my host from a C# project. I'm learning PHP and mysqli to be able to do this. I'm stuck about where to actually sort the information. The query comes from my C# app through a $_POST variable and gets the requested data. But then it seems like i'm limited as how to get it back to my app. I can either send it as one long string and reorganize it in C#. Or create complicated for loops and still need to do a lot of sorting on the C# side. I'm sure i'm just unfamiliar with PHP and mysqli. Can anyone recommend  a workflow? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use something like JSON to talk back and forth between PHP and C# applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways you can pass it back to your C# application.  JSON and XML are very popular.  For this answer I will discuss using JSON.

On the PHP side you will want to take your data and convert it into it's JSON form with [json_encode](http://us.php.net/json_encode).  On the C# side you will convert it from JSON into a C# object.  While there are ways to do this built into C# ([DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) and [JavaScriptSerializer](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/mref/T_System_Web_Script_Serialization_JavaScriptSerializer.aspx)), the best option in .NET due to implementation and performance is [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

Updating... adding a rough example.

**PHP**

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT One, Two FROM MyTable")) {
    $jsonResult = json_encode($result);     

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

// Now send back $jsonResult
```

**C# (using JSON.net/JObject... you could also make an actual object to deserialize to)**

```
string phpResponse = /* Add wherever you got your data from */;
JObject myResult = JObject.Parse(phpResponse);
```